# MPMoviePlayerController Audio show "Done" Button

Tags: ios, button, mpmovieplayercontroller, audio-streaming

I use the MPMoviePlayerController to Play an Audio Stream.
My code follows the example at:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/video/getting-mpmovieplayercontroller-to-cooperate-with-ios4-3-2-ipad-and-earlier-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html

Everything works fine, but while the stream is playing there is no "done"
button to close the Player.

I tested it first with a normal .mp3 file. With the file the only
possibility I found is to skip to the end,
so the player gets the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`
notification
(but this won't work on an endless stream, since there is no timeline to
skip to the end).

I tried various styles like `[mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];` with no succes.

In the documentation at
[MPMoviePlayerController Class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmovieplayercontroller) stands:

> This class plays any movie or audio
>   file supported in iOS. This includes
>   both streamed content and fixed-length
>   files

Is there a possibility to display that button while playing some audio
content, or has anyone another solution?

I tried to show you an screenshot but "new users can only post a maximum of two hyperlinks".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i found a solution by my self.

Using the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` class, instead of `MPMoviePlayerController`  solved the problem:

```
NSString *path = @"http://yourstreamingurl.com/stream.m3u";

MPMoviePlayerViewController* mpviewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];

mpviewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;  
[self presentModalViewController:mpviewController animated:YES];
[[mpviewController moviePlayer] play];
```

Comment: It works perfect and furthermore MPViewController auto-closes itself when "Done" pressed.

Answer (score 2):

For playing file locally, remove

```
mpviewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
```

Other wise it will return

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException reason An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer
```